# React Native: Animate shrinking header with tabs and faltlist in tab

Tags: react-native

Im trying to create a view with an animated shrinking header with a tabview that contains tabs with flatlist(such as google play). See Image.
[image]

I'm using react-navigation with a TabNavigator. The header is a component with a fixed height, currently above the TabNavigator. The header is fixed above the tabs all the time taking precious space.

I've tried  [React Native: Animate shrinking header with tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44071308/react-native-animate-shrinking-header-with-tabs) but I can't get it to work because I gonna integrate flat list in to tab.
This article is using scrollview in tab panel.

Certainly, I am looking for solution for using flatlist.

Comment: [This](https://medium.com/appandflow/react-native-scrollview-animated-header-10a18cb9469e) might help you:

Comment: thanks, but I have checked it. since I have to use tab , i can not it.

Comment: @BennySudibyo Flatlist inherits the props of scrollview, so it seems like replacing scrollview with flatlist will work.